# No such property: sonatypeRepo for class: org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.deployer.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer

Tags: android, design-patterns, github

I am trying to clone "Pattern view for android. That one using the lock or unlock" from this project link: [Git Repo](https://github.com/geftimov/android-patternview), but I am facing this error in my android studio 2.3

```
No such property: sonatypeRepo for class:org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.deployer.DefaultGroovyMavenDeploye
```

I don't know what is wrong, any help please am new at android and is the first time to use Github.

Comment: Can you post your exact steps? I just tested for android 2.2 and it worked

Comment: do you mean image for each step i take? @sup4eli

Comment: Well, it's just that I've encountered few questions when folks just won't put the dependency statement in the correct gradle file or had a typo. If you could specify your steps somehow or review a similar question. Hope I'm being helpful.